# best way to output an image with php

Tags: php, image, file-io

I have a script called "image.php" that is used to count impressions and then print the image.

This script is called in this way:

```
<img src="path/image.php?id=12345" />
```

And it's used very often by my users, i see thousand of request per day

So I am looking to understand what is the best way to output the image at the end of this script:

**Method 1 (actually in use):**

```
header("Content-type: $mime"); //$mime is found with getimagesize function
readfile("$image_url");
exit;
```

**Method 2 (pretty sure that is slowest):**

```
header("Content-type: $mime");
echo  file_get_contents("$image_url");
exit;
```

**Method 3:**

```
header('Location: '.$image_url);
exit();
```

Is method 3 better / faster than method 1?

Answer (score 2):

Ok first of all Method 3 is way faster when redirected to the original file.

The first 2 methods need file access and read the file and also they don't use the browser cache!

Also when you store the rendered images, you can better let apache handle your static files. 
Apache is way faster than PHP and it uses the right browser caching (3 or 4 times faster wouldn't be a suprise).

What happens is when you request a static file, apache send the Last-Modified header 
If your client requests the same image again it sends the If-Modified-Since header with that same date. If the file isn't changed you server respond with an 304 Not Modified header without any data wich saves you a lot IO operations (Besides the ETAG header wich is also used)

For your impressions count of the image, you could create a cronjob that parses your apache access logs so the end-user won't even notice it. But in your case it's easier to count the impressions in your script and then redirect

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what readfile does is it reads the file directly into the output buffer while file_get_contents loads the file into the memory (string). So, when you output the results the data is copied from the memory into the output buffer, making it two times slower than readfile.